# Правильно ли: "включИм", "включенО"?

Tags: фонетика

"ВключИм", включенО" — правильно ли?

Answer (score 3):

Да, Вы указали нормативное ударение. Но в речевой практике повсеместно слышим "вклЮчит", вклЮчено". В списках для ЕГЭ это слово было до недавнего времени. В этом году исключили как не соответствующее реальному употреблению. Можно сказать, включИт - норма устаревающая. Скорее всего, в новых словарях указано, что это разговорный вариант. К сожалению, у меня только Аванесов, но это восьмидесятые годы. Там еще вариант "вклЮчит" дается как неправильный!!! Аналогично: сорИт - сОрит , облегчИт - облЕгчит" и т. п.